# How do I call a plotting function with a possible parameter that specifies the path where the files should be saved in python?

Tags: python, plot, directory

I have a plotting function that outputs a  matplotlib plot as a pdf  or a jpg: Currently they are automatically saved to the root directory in a specific file. Now I would like the option to call the function with another optional parameter that specifies the path to the folder where the plots should be saved. Additionally, if no path is specified, the plots should be saved by default in the root.
This is along the lines of the code I currently have (I took out some stuff to make it clearer):

```
def main(desired_path=""):
  ...
  plotting_function(parameters, desired_path)

def plotting_function(parameters, desired_path):
  ... #plot some stuff
  script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  results_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'Plots/')
  file_name = "plot1"

  if not os.path.isdir(results_dir):
     os.makedirs(results_dir)
  
  plt.savefig(results_dir + file_name + ".png")
```

Now, my idea was that I would add another folder with

```
all_plots_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'All_plots/'
if not os.path.isdir(results_dir):
     os.makedirs(results_dir)
```

since I wanted to have a mother folder where all the folders with the different plots go into.
However, I don't know how to add the desired_path to this?
Additionally I thought I could add a default version like this:

```
if desired_path == "":
  default_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Meaning that I would check if the parameter for the path was actually entered by the user and if not use os to specify the root folder as a default (though I am not sure if I did that correctly.

Could anyone help me how I do this correctly and additionally include the option for specifying a path?
Thank you!